# Particle collision exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, collision

**Take the following problem**

> In the PADME experiment, positrons of $E_b = 550 MeV$ collide against a
> fixed target. Assuming the existence of a dark photon $A$, we assume
> that the following reaction is possible: $e^+ + e^- \longrightarrow \gamma + A$ where $\gamma$ is an
> ordinary photon. The photon is detected and its energy $E_{\gamma}$, as well as
> the angle $\theta$ it makes with the direction of the positron beam, are
> measured.
>
> 1. Compute the expression from which one can derive the mass $m_A$ of the dark photon from experimental data.
> 2. Compute the maximum possible mass of the dark photon that can be produced with this method.
> 3. Assuming that the annihilation of the positrons happens in a state with total angular momentum $J = 0$, compute the energy distribution of
>    the photons in the rest frame of the $e^+e^-$ system and in the laboratory
>    frame

**Here is what I have done so far:**

1. To compute the mass $m_A$ we can use the conservation of energy and momentum along $x$ and $y$

$$
\begin{cases}
E_b = E_{\gamma}+\sqrt{m_a^2c^4+c^2p_A^2}\\
P_{e^+} = \sqrt{\frac{E_{e^+}}{c^2}-m_{e^+}c^2} = \frac{E_{\gamma}}{c}cos\theta + P_A cos\phi\\
0 = \frac{E_{\gamma}}{c}sin\theta - P_A sin\phi
\end{cases}
$$

from the last two we have

$$
\begin{cases}
P_A cos \phi = P^{(x)}_{e^+} - \frac{E_{\gamma}}{c}cos\theta\\
P_A sin\phi = \frac{E_{\gamma}}{c} sin \theta
\end{cases}
$$

which leads to

$$
P_A^2 = (P_{e^+} - \frac{E_{\gamma}}{c}cos\theta)^2 + (\frac{E_{\gamma}}{c} sin \theta)^2 = P_{e^+}^2 + \frac{E_{\gamma}^2}{c^2}-2 P_{e^+}\frac{E_{\gamma}}{c}cos \theta
$$

from this equation we can obtain $P_A$ which substituted into the first one (conservation of energy) gives $m_A$.

2. Since the energy of $A$ is constrained, and given the formula $E_A = \sqrt{m_A^2c^4 + P_A^2 c^2}$ in order to maximize $m_A$ we need to minimize $P_A$ which happens for $\theta = 0$ therefore we use the same procedure as before and take $\theta = 0$.
3. I have no idea how to do it

**My questions**

- Did I do it right so far?
- How do you solve the 3 point?
- Why do we care about the value of $J$?

Comment: "Why do we care about the value of J?" Non zero angular momentum in the reaction means the reaction is not spherically symmetric.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess this is partially also the answer to the second question about the energy distribution.